# How to use breadcrumb for href and router link in angular6

Tags: angular6, angular2-services

I have created global breadcrumb component and it is working for routerlink but not working for href..How can i use this breadcrumb component for both routerlink and href.If you see my stackblitz code you can easily understand.

```
<li><a href="/home" >Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/c1" >C1</a></li>
```

Comment: you can checkout https://api.amexio.org/api/v5.5/index.html#/breadcrumb-demo

Comment: Already checked..but not use

Comment: Its not clear what you're trying to get. Try to edit your question with more details of the problem and the result you're trying to get

Comment: Not sure, but maybe you're trying to create a breadcrumbs component that can be used with routerlink in one place and in hrefs in another place? If so, and I get what you're trying to do, then you're probably passing the routerlinks of href from outside of this component?

Comment: No..I am trying for href only..rite now i am using only href instead of routerlink..how can i do breadcrumb for href?